# Multiple GPUs in Cuda - Working code before, but not any more

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I've recently come across trouble running with multiple NVidia GPUs in a Cuda application. The attached code is able to reproduce the problem consistently on my system in both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 (Windows 7, Cuda 9.2, Nvidia driver 398.26, 1xGTX1080 and 1xGTX960). I am building for the correct compute capabilities for my cards (5.2 and 6.1).

Specifically, after the first GPU has been initialized, I am unable to get any function calls on the second GPU to work. The error code is consistently "CudaErrorMemoryAllocation". It fails in the Nvidia profiler and in both debug and release builds. I can initialize on the GPUs in either order and reproduce the problem.

This problem came up when trying to scale my current application, which is a large pipeline of image processing algorithms. There can be several independent instances of this pipeline, and due to memory limitations, multiple cards will be required. The main reason I'm so confused by this issue is that I've had it working before - I have a Visual Profile session that I ran a couple years ago that shows my same cards behaving as expected. The only difference I'm aware of is that it was in Cuda 8.0.

Any ideas?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cuda.h"

#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

// Function for each thread to run
void gpuThread(int gpuIdx, bool* result)
{
    cudaSetDevice(gpuIdx); // Set gpu index

    // Create an int array on CPU
    int* hostMemory = new int[1000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        hostMemory[i] = i;

    // Allocate and copy to GPU
    int* gpuMemory;
    cudaMalloc(&gpuMemory, 1000000 * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(gpuMemory, hostMemory, 1000000 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Synchronize and check errors
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if (error != CUDA_SUCCESS)
    {
        result[0] = false;
        return;
    }

    result[0] =  true;
}

int main()
{
    bool result1 = false;
    bool result2 = false;

    std::thread t1(gpuThread, 0, &result1);
    std::thread t2(gpuThread, 1, &result2);

    t1.join();  // Wait for both threads to complete
    t2.join();

    if (!result1 || !result2) // Verify our threads returned success
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Passed\n";

    std::cout << "Press a key to exit!\n";
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will probably get a lot more clarity on what might be happening if you add compete error cursing on all the API calls. Also what happens if you don't use threading? You say the only change is the CUDA version, but if several years have passed, then you have a bunch of OS and toolchain updates, a different display driver. You are going to have to got through all of them one by one....

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have posted the example code without threading; the problem is the same if it runs on one thread. I do have thorough error checking in the full application, and the result on the second GPU is consistently "CudaErrorMemoryAllocation". Luckily, the code lives on a non-networked PC and the OS hasn't been updated at all. I also know the last time this was working was with the same VS2013 installation. Today is going to be spent rolling back Cuda and driver versions to see if I can reproduce the old behavior, but two years of commits is a lot to sift through.

Comment: After a day of uninstalling and reinstalling programs, it appears that this is an issue with the 398.26 driver. The newer version, 399.07, works as expected.

Comment: Do you want to add that as an answer so we can get this question off the unanswered list?

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to this site and wasn't sure how to clean this up now that it's sorted out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. In a few days you will be able to come back and accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of uninstalling and reinstalling programs, it appears that this is an issue with the 398.26 driver. The newer version, 399.07, works as expected.